# DatePicker - How to display date Month name in three characters instead of number

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uidatepicker

This is my first ever attempt at Swift or an iPhone app, so needless to say I'm not sure how to do many things at this point.

I want to show the date like this in my textfield

```
02 Feb 2016
```

But right now it displays like this

```
 2/7/16
```

here is my code

```
@IBAction func dateTextFieldBeginEditing(sender: UITextField) {


       // let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date

        sender.inputView = datePickerView

        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    }

    func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {


        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle


        dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle

        departureDateTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set date format like this!! This will give you date like **02 Feb 2016**.
Also remove **dateStyle** and **timeStyle** property from your code.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"

dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

This gives me output as **09 FEB 2016**

Comment: Please check your code, this works perfectly fine. Refer my edited answer.

Comment: @ iOSEnthusiatic  Okay Its working but datepicker is showing AM/PM and also week days which I don't want.

Comment: you've already set datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date to show only dates.

Comment: yeah I mistakenly commented that line.. Its okay now.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
        departureDateTextField.text = dateString

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let timestamp = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .NoStyle)
print(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add an Extension of NSDate

```
extension NSDate {
    func dateStringWithFormat(format: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

2) Make two public variables

```
var datePicker:UIDatePicker?
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
```

3) Add to UIDatePicker

```
let dateString = NSDate().dateStringWithFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
print("Today's Date: "+dateString)
datePicker?.date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 func datePicker(sender:UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"

    //// dd MMM yyyy == 02 Feb 2016

    let dateData = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)

    departureDateTextField.text = dateData

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.datePicker.backgroundColor = .white
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    let loc = Locale.init(identifier: "pt-BR")
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.locale = loc
    self.datePicker.calendar = calendar
    self.datePicker.locale = loc

    self.datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleDatePicker), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
}

@objc func handleDatePicker()
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    let loc = Locale.init(identifier: "pt-BR")
    dateFormatter.locale = loc
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: self.datePicker.date))
 }
```

Comment: sorry that answer is giving for other question it's post by mistake [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056329/swift-change-date-picker-language]