# Swift change date picker language

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I want to change format of month represent in my UIDatePicker. I tried:

```
self.datePicker = UIDatePicker()
self.datePicker.backgroundColor = .white
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
let loc = Locale.init(identifier: "uk")
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.locale = loc
self.datePicker.calendar = calendar
```

After that, month representation suppose to be in ukranian, but it still in other language.

Comment: Did you try directly setting the picker's `locale` property instead of the calendar's `locale` property?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should assign `loc` to the date picker [locale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615995-locale) property:

```
let loc = Locale(identifier: "uk")
self.datePicker.locale = loc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know way to change global locale so that each formatter would use it?

Comment: @Erumaru https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252233/global-constants-file-in-swift https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-define-global-constant-in-swift.html https://medium.com/swift-india/defining-global-constants-in-swift-a80d9e5cbd42